# Unable to create a .pfx file

Tags: certificate, digital-certificate, pfx, makecert

I have created the .pvk and .cer files using the makecert.exe (on commandline) as per - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff699202.aspx

In my folder the .pvk and .cer files are available. However, when I run the pvk2pfx utility, the .pfx is not created instead I get a prompt for how to use the utility.

Attached is the screenshot of the cmd prompt. I've also tried it at the MSVC bin folder and the behavior is the same.

Kindly help.

[makecert and pvk2pfx - Command Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSzvM.png)

Comment: I am trying to build an installer (.exe) using inno setup. I need the publisher info to be displayed instead of "Unknown". So, I guess I need to sign it. I was thinking of using signtool which is readily available with MSVC. As I need a pfx file to sign it I am trying to create one using the steps mentioned above in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need code sign certificate with private key. Generate request, send it to CA, buy code sign certificate, place certificate into certificate store and use signtool. Specify thumbprint of codesign certificate when using signtool.

More info can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingCodeSigningCertificatesToSignDownloadedMSIsAndBuildReputationWithIE9SmartScreen.aspx).

Documentation on signtool can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).